# Why is "whois" timing out on my Mac's terminal but apparent working fine in Network Utility?

Tags: macos, networking, mac, terminal, whois

I'm running Mac OS X 10.10.2 (Yosemite) and when I do the following in “Terminal,” my request times out:

```
> whois google.com
whois: connect(): Operation timed out
```

I also downloaded `jwhois` with no luck:

```
> jwhois google.com
[Querying whois.internic.net]
[Unable to connect to remote host]
```

However, when I try a `whois` search from the “Network Utility,” it works instantly:

[image]

Any thoughts on whats going on? I would think it’s an ISP issue but it seems to work fine in “Network Utility.”

Comment: I have the same issue on El Capitan 10.11.6. Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

You have likely accidentally blocked outgoing connections to your local whois server in your firewall.  If you are using a firewall such as Little Snitch.  Go to Little Snitch Configuration -> All Rules, and search for Terminal.  Check which rules you have set there.
In my case I had a rule that specified:

`Deny outgoing connections via whois to domain iana.org`

It looked like this:

[image]

After disabling this rule the problem was resolved.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Good point! i had used the embed image button previously but somehow it ended up as a link.  I've fixed that, and also added text.